# How to use Polymer's google-client-loader and google-signin together?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, polymer-1.0, google-signin

I want to authenticate the user using `google-signin` and than be able to make authorized API requests to my endpoints API through `google-client-loader`.

How can you combine them to allow this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the authentication via the `google-signin` element has happened, all calls via the `gapi.client` methods will be authenticated automatically.

I have an old Polymer 0.5 sample that does this with a Google API but the same works for your own endpoints and the behavior isn't that much different in Polymer 1.0:

https://github.com/Scarygami/google-signin-samples/blob/master/elements/google-plus-friends.html#L57

```
<google-signin
    ...
    is-authorized="{{_authorized}}">

<google-client-loader
      id="your_api"
      name="your_api"
      version="your_api_version"
      app-id="your-appengine-id"
      on-google-api-load="_apiLoaded"></google-client-loader>


...

_makeRequest: function () {
  if (this._authorized && this.$.your_api.api) {
    // authentication has happened and api has been loaded

    // this call will automatically get authorization headers
    this.$.your_api.api.your_resource.your_method({<params>}).then(...)
  }
}
```

PS. I've also created an element that will automatically create elements for all your API methods so you can access your API declaratively (wrapping the google-client-loader inside): https://github.com/Scarygami/discovery-api-elements/

Comment: pretty cool , thanks ! it would be awesome if there was a way to preload the client library , instead of having to deal with async and checking if it's loaded and such ... just an idea.